# ¿Cómo hacer que el fondo se mueva horizontalmente?

Tags: pygame, background

hola estoy practicando en pygame de como poder controlar el movimiento del fondo en mi juego
como lo hago porfavor si no seria mucha molestia este es el codigo porfavor no jusguen soy nuevisimo no puedo hacer mover el fondo de pantalla de un lado para el otro

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

windows_width = 800
windows_Height = 500
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
OTHERCOLOR = (0, 0, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windows_width, windows_Height))


class Environment:
      def __init__(self):
           self.start = "images/title2.png"
           self.background = "images/ciudad1.png"
           self.running = True
           self.posX = -30
           self.posY = 0
           self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()


  def Main_loop(self):
       screen.fill(OTHERCOLOR)
       init = pygame.image.load(self.start).convert()
       screen.blit(init, [0, 0])
       start_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
       start_text = start_font.render("Press s to Start", 0, (255, 0, 0))
       screen.blit(start_text, (350, 420))
       pygame.display.flip()
       while self.running:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == K_s:
                      self.Game_loop()
                   if event.key == K_d:
                      self.posX -= 1
                      self.clock.tick(30)
                      print("buttonHasBeenPushe")

                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   self.running = False
       pygame.quit()

  def Game_loop(self):
      Background = pygame.image.load(self.background).convert()
      background = pygame.transform.scale(Background, (2000, 1000))
      screen.blit(background, [self.posX, self.posY])
      pygame.display.update()
```

root = Environment()
root.Main_loop()
no logro mover el fondo poravor que alguien brida una colaboracion

Comment: Por favor, coloca algo más descriptivo como título de la pregunta. No quiero ser rudo, pero creo que tampoco falta que repitas que eres nuevo, ya que todos podemos plantear preguntas correctamente aún cuando no tengamos experiencia. Un saludo.

Comment: esque soy nuevo perdon jajaja esque no puedo hacer que el fondo no se mueva horizontalmente

Comment: Mira, por allí sale el título: "fondo de juego no se mueve horizontalmente", suena mejor que "soy yo de nuevo...". Al editar, aprovecha para agregar la etiqueta `python`. Un saludo.

Comment: oh rayos ya moleste esta comunidad peron no es mi intencion es mas la emocion y esas cosas pero mi problema aqui esque deberia disminuir la posicion del fondo del presionando un boton pero no me sale

Comment: No hay molestia (de mi parte), te digo estas cosas con el afán de ayudarte a entender las reglas del sitio y con ello mejorar tus posibilidades de encontrar ayuda. No estaría mal que te des una vuelta por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), por ejemplo, lee [ask]. Edita tu pregunta y explica cual es el problema, mejora el título, incluye la etiqueta del lenguaje.  Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido Mike! c:

## Explicación

El problema está en que la función `Game_loop` (la función donde dibujas el fondo) solo se ejecuta cuando el usuario presiona la tecla "s" para iniciar el juego. Para hacer que Pygame mueva algo, este algo tiene que redibujarse luego de que su posición sea actualizada.

## Solución

Separé el bucle del juego en dos bucles. Por que? Por que existen dos partes del juego que hacen cosas muy diferentes. La primera sección es en la que el usuario decide si iniciar el juego o cerrarlo, y la segunda sección es el juego en sí.
Además, eso de tenerlo separado en dos bucles te va ayudar a evitar cosas como que el jugador intente iniciar el juego cuando ya está iniciado.

Aquí te dejo la modificación que le hice a tu clase Enviroment:

```
class Environment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = "images/title2.png"
        self.background = "images/ciudad1.png"
        self.running = True
        self.posX = -30
        self.posY = 0
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def exit(self):
        pygame.quit()
        


    def Main_loop(self):
        screen.fill(OTHERCOLOR)
        init = pygame.image.load(self.start).convert()
        screen.blit(init, [0, 0])
        start_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        start_text = start_font.render("Press s to Start", 0, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(start_text, (350, 420))
        pygame.display.flip()

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        # Primer while. En este while espero dos tipos de eventos: Que el usuario inicie el juego con la tecla s o que decida cerrar la ventana #
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        start = False
        
        while not start:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_s:
                        # Creo el fondo
                        Background = pygame.image.load(self.background).convert()
                        background = pygame.transform.scale(Background, (2000, 1000))
                        
                        # Este bucle while dejará de ejecutarse dando espacio al siguiente bucle while
                        start = True

                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    # Sale del juego
                    self.exit()

                    # Sale de la función, el segundo while NO se ejecuta debido a esto
                    return

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        # Segundo while. Este es el bucle del juego.                                                                                            #
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

        running = True

        while running:
            #pinto toda la pantalla de negro cada vez que termino de redibujar el fondo.
            #Esto es para evitar que al moverse el fondo aparesca repetido.
            #Quita esta linea, prueba mi código y entenderás bien a que me refiero.
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_d:
                        self.posX -= 1
                        self.clock.tick(30)
                        print("buttonHasBeenPushe")

                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    self.exit()
                    return
            

            # Redibujo el fondo sobre el fondo negro
            screen.blit(background, [self.posX, self.posY])

            #actualizo lo que se muestra en la ventana.
            pygame.display.flip()
```